# How to have bar labels be names in Plotly for R

Tags: r, r-plotly

So I'm trying to make a bar chart that displays the most popular airports that flew to Chicago. For some reason, I'm finding it to be extremely difficult to have my bars be labeled by the airport names specifically.

I have a data frame called ty

```
> ty
                                                     Name
1   Atlanta, GA: Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International
2                                 New York, NY: LaGuardia
3      Minneapolis, MN: Minneapolis-St Paul International
4              Los Angeles, CA: Los Angeles International
5                        Denver, CO: Denver International
6       Washington, DC: Ronald Reagan Washington National
7                      Orlando, FL: Orlando International
8           Phoenix, AZ: Phoenix Sky Harbor International
9                 Detroit, MI: Detroit Metro Wayne County
10                  Las Vegas, NV: McCarran International
11         San Francisco, CA: San Francisco International
12 Dallas/Fort Worth, TX: Dallas/Fort Worth International
13                        Boston, MA: Logan International
14           Philadelphia, PA: Philadelphia International
15               Newark, NJ: Newark Liberty International
```

I also have a data frame called df

```
      id numArrivals
1  10397         964
2  12953         962
3  13487         883
4  12892         823
5  11292         776
6  11278         771
7  13204         725
8  14107         700
9  11433         672
10 12889         647
11 14771         611
12 11298         580
13 10721         569
14 14100         567
15 11618         488
```

The id corresponds to the airport name `10397` is `Atlanta, GA: Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International` and they continue in that order.

However, when I run:

```
plotly::plot_ly(df,x=ty["Name"],y=df$numArrivals,type="bar",color=I("rgba(0,92,124,1)"))
```

I am given [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJXC1.png) chart.

How can I make the labels of my bars into the names of the airport rather than just numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to use ggplotly() to create your plot. I used the code below to create a small example.

```
example <- data.frame(airport = c("Atlanta, GA: Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International","New York, NY: LaGuardia","Minneapolis, MN: Minneapolis-St Paul International"),
              id = c(10397,12953,13487),
              numArrivals = c(964,962,883),stringsAsFactors = F)

library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

a <- ggplot(example,aes(x=airport,y=numArrivals,fill=id)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()
ggplotly(a)
```

The final result looks like this.
[image]